# Subsets and their respective totals in one line

Tags: functions

I want all subsets of the digits 1 through 9 containing exactly 2 elements. But I also want their respective totals. All from a single line command.

I already know how to generate the subsets:

```
Subsets[Range@9, {2}]
```

This gives {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},... etc.

But I am looking for something like this:

So {{1,2},3},{{1,3,},4},{{1,4},5},... etc..

I can generate the totals separately:

```
Total/@Subsets[Range@9, {2}]
```

But I can't generate it all at once, in one line. Any ideas? I have a feeling a pure function might help.

Comment: `{#, Total[#]} & /@ Subsets[Range@9, {2}]`

Comment: Thank you. I never thought to map a pure function to the expression.

Comment: A lot can be done with pure functions (here it applies to the evaluated result, not the function) - I must admit that most of what I do in Mathematica is chains of pure functions (if practically plausible). It is not necessarily the most readable form but perfectly capable of accomplishing most tasks.

Comment: You can also use replace with a suitable rule: `Subsets[Range@9, {2}] /. {x_, y_} -> {{x, y}, Total[{x, y}]} `

Comment: `Transpose@Through[{Identity, Map[Total]}[Subsets[Range@9, {2}]]]`